# Custom coordinate operation in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, well-known-text

I'm trying to create [custom Coordinate Operation](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/configuration/crshandling/coordtransforms.html#define-a-custom-coordinate-operation) in GeoServer version 2.22.0, but I get this error in the `geoserver.log`:

> WARN   [referencing.factory] - Error creating transformation: CONCAT_MT[ INVERSE_MT[ PARAM_MT["NADCON", PARAMETER["Latitude difference file", "Slovakia_JTSK03_to_JTSK.LAS"], PARAMETER["Longitude difference file", "Slovakia_JTSK03_to_JTSK.LOS"]]], PARAM_MT["Coordinate Frame rotation (geog2D domain)", PARAMETER["X-axis translation", 485.021], PARAMETER["Y-axis translation", 169.465], PARAMETER["Z-axis translation", 483.839], PARAMETER["X-axis rotation", -7.786342], PARAMETER["Y-axis rotation", -4.397554], PARAMETER["Z-axis rotation", -4.102655], PARAMETER["Scale difference", 0]]]

Unfortunately the log doesn't contain anything other relevant to the transformation. I have tried to set the logging level to GEOSERVER_DEVELOPER_LOGGING, GEOTOOLS_DEVELOPER_LOGGING and VERBOSE_LOGGING, but I did not find anything more.

This is the content of **epsg_operations.properties** file:

```
4156,4326=CONCAT_MT[ \
  INVERSE_MT[ \
    PARAM_MT["NADCON", \
      PARAMETER["Latitude difference file", "Slovakia_JTSK03_to_JTSK.LAS"], \
      PARAMETER["Longitude difference file", "Slovakia_JTSK03_to_JTSK.LOS"]]], \
  PARAM_MT["Coordinate Frame rotation (geog2D domain)", \
    PARAMETER["X-axis translation", 485.021], \
    PARAMETER["Y-axis translation", 169.465], \
    PARAMETER["Z-axis translation", 483.839], \
    PARAMETER["X-axis rotation", -7.786342], \
    PARAMETER["Y-axis rotation", -4.397554], \
    PARAMETER["Z-axis rotation", -4.102655], \
    PARAMETER["Scale difference", 0]]]
```

When I remove the **"NADCON"** transformation or the **"Coordinate Frame rotation (geog2D domain)"** transformation, then it works. So the syntax for these transformations should be correct.

I have also tried to combine the **"NADCON"** transformation with **"Molodenski"** transformation from GeoServer examples and that also works.

Is there some limitation to what transformations you can chain together?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Comment: @IanTurton I have added more log info to my question. Previously I have shortened the log, because I didn't find anything relevant in the logs.